# Обновить данные после загрузки страницы vue

Tags: vue.js, framework7

Есть страница, при переходе на нее с помощью beforeMount() я запускаю функцию в methods которая загружает данные из БД. Проблема в том что когда я перехожу на другую страницу (с помощью router) и возвращаюсь обратно на первую, данные остаются прежние, а мне нужно заново их запросить в БД (потому что они обновятся).
Как можно обновлять страницу при каждом переходе на нее. (beforeMount отрабатывает только один раз)

Comment: а почему не сделать через asyncData?

Comment: Приведите пример двух маршрутов, которые вы используете. Есть одна идейка.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать отслеживать изменение маршрута в компоненте [так](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81n%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)